# Apache2 virtualhost env variable undefined on Docket

Tags: apache, docker, vue.js

I use a Docker Hub image (official httpd:2.4) to create an apache2 container for my webapp.

I added many vHosts to my httpd-vhosts.conf like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@first.local
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/first"
    ServerName first.local
    ServerAlias www.first.local
    ErrorLog "logs/first.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/first.local-access_log" common
    SetEnv HELLO 'Hello world'
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_env is enabled by default in the image, and I included correctly httpds-vhosts.conf into httpd.conf (I can access my vhost) but I can't retrieve the environment variable HELLO into my app.

My app is a VueJS app which use : process.env to access all the environement variable, but HELLO is not visible (whereas other setted directly into my source code app are visible).

What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks